# Callbacks for USB HID API in OsX are never called for game pad or anything else

Tags: macos, hid, gamepad

I am trying to detect and use a gamepad attached to my Mac in my game.
I am using the IOKit for this but without success.
The gamepad is recognized as I downloaded a Mac app that views all gamepads attached.
It is a Logitech F310 and I have set it to DirectInput.
I am calling setupInput inside awakeFromNib but none of the callbacks are ever called.
There is no error or exception thrown.
I have no idea why the callbacks are not called.
What am I doing wrong?
I am thinking maybe it's an issue with the run loop. I tried both CFRunLoopGetMain and CFRunLoopGetCurrent.

Not sure what else to do.

Edit: As suggested by someone I tried to put the same GamePad code in a new project and it worked.
There is some difference in the structure of the classes but I couldn't make it work in my app even if I tried to replicate the classes.
My app use AppDelegate and NSOpenGLView. Strangely enough it doesn't have an NSViewController.
The minimal app use NSOpenGLView but also NSResponder and when I put the gamepad code inside the(custom) NSResponder class it "works"(detects the gamepad and responds to input).
I tried to add that custom class to my app but it "didn't work".
What am I missing?

```
void gamepadWasAdded(void* inContext, IOReturn inResult, void* inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {
    NSLog(@"Gamepad was plugged in");
}

void gamepadWasRemoved(void* inContext, IOReturn inResult, void* inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef device) {
    NSLog(@"Gamepad was unplugged");
}

void gamepadAction(void* inContext, IOReturn inResult, void* inSender, IOHIDValueRef value) {
    NSLog(@"Gamepad talked!");
    IOHIDElementRef element = IOHIDValueGetElement(value);
    NSLog(@"Element: %@", element);
    int elementValue = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(value);
    NSLog(@"Element value: %i", elementValue);
}

-(void) setupInput {
    //get a HID manager reference
    hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

    //define the device to search for, via usage page and usage key
    NSMutableDictionary* criterion = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [criterion setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: kHIDPage_GenericDesktop]
                  forKey: (NSString*)CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey)];
    [criterion setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: kHIDUsage_GD_Joystick]
                  forKey: (NSString*)CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey)];

    //search for the device
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(hidManager,
                                  (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)criterion);

    //register our callback functions
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(hidManager, gamepadWasAdded,
                                               (__bridge void*)self);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(hidManager, gamepadWasRemoved,
                                              (__bridge void*)self);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(hidManager, gamepadAction,
                                           (__bridge void*)self);

    //scedule our HIDManager with the current run loop, so that we
    //are able to recieve events from the hardware.
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(),
                                    kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    //open the HID manager, so that it can start routing events
    //to our callbacks.
    IOHIDManagerOpen(hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);

}

// Put our timer in -awakeFromNib, so it can start up right from the beginning
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    renderTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.001   //a 1ms time interval
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:renderTimer
                                 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:renderTimer
                                 forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode]; //Ensure timer fires during resize
    [self setupInput];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have found the issue.
The problem was that my Mac app was in sandbox and I didn't check mark the Hardware/USB check box.
With this option checked it works with the original code.